# In-memory database using Data Structures and Algorithms specifically in C Programming Language

Tags: c, data-structures, in-memory-database

How do you go about creating an in-memory database using structures specifically in C programming?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: I suppose this would nuke the page, as it is too general a question to give a single short answer to.

Comment: I would like to create a gpa calculator in memory database. We are using C programming language. I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking over the code for sqlite:

http://www.sqlite.org/

It is implemented in C and provides a single-process SQL database backend.  It can support an "in-memory" mode out of the box:

http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

The sqlite code is quite compact and there is a fair amount of API documentation on the website.  It might give you a useful case study for your own work.